# C++ no match for 'operator=' in my custom object array

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-keyword, nachos

I have a class called KernelLock, and I am creating an array of KernelLocks called myLockArray. I declare it like this: `KernelLock myLockArray[150];`

When I try to add a new KernelLock to myLockArray, I get the aforementioned error. Here is the exact line I get the error on:

```
myLockArray[initializedLocksCounter] = new KernelLock(myAddrSpace, newLock);
```

and here is the exact error:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 'myLockArray[initializedLocksCounter] = (((KernelLock*)operator new(8u)), (<anonymous>->KernelLock::KernelLock(myAddrSpace, newLock), <anonymous>))
```

In case it helps, I am compiling with gcc through Nachos.

Comment: new returns a pointer, not the object itself.

Comment: How do I return the object itself?

Comment: _"When I try to add a new KernelLock to myLockArray"_ Wait, what? You have an array of 150 KernelLocks. How can you add another one? Sounds like you're confusing Java and C++..... this is not an array of pointers......

Comment: Or you might just store the pointer.    try  myLockArray[initializedLocksCounter] = *(new KernelLock(myAddrSpace, newLock))

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Because memory leaks are fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
KernelLock myLockArray[150];
```

This is an array that contains 150 kernel locks.

> When I try to add a new KernelLock to myLockArray

You cannot add any objects to an array. The size of an array is always constant. It always has 150 locks.

```
myLockArray[initializedLocksCounter] = new KernelLock(myAddrSpace, newLock);
```

This is wrong. `new` returns the address of a dynamically allocated object. You're trying to assign that address to the existing `KernelLock` object at the index `initializedLocksCounter`. You cannot assign an address to a non-pointer object (unless the object has corresponding (non-explicit) constructor).

If you want a growing array, use `std::vector<KernelLock>`

Comment: How would I do this with vectors?

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant I recommend checking out one of the suggested books [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for the basics.

Answer (score 3):

```
KernelLock myLockArray[150];
```

Creates an array of 150 `KernelLock`s.  You then then try to assign a `KernelLock *` to it.  If you want pointers then you need to change your array to:

```
KernelLock* myLockArray[150];
```

If you don't want pointers then you just need to change your assignment to

```
myLockArray[initializedLocksCounter] = KernelLock(myAddrSpace, newLock);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are fundamentally misunderstanding what an object is in C++. It's not like in Java.

Your 150 `KernelLock` objects are 150 `KernelLock` objects. Not pointers, and not references. And there are 150 of them. You cannot dynamically "expand" the array whenever you please, and doing so with `new` is dynamic allocation which requires managing pointers (`KernelLock*`).

From the sounds of it, you actually want a `std::vector<KernelLock>`.

*[Here are some resources for learning the basics of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).*

Comment: should I use vector<KernelLock> or vector<*KernelLock>?

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant: `vector<*KernelLock>` is not even valid syntax. You should use what I wrote in my answer. Which C++ book are you using? Guessing isn't a good way to program :(

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use a value of type `KernelLock*` as element of an array of `KernelLock`'s. You simply do:

```
myLockArray[i] = KernelLock(myAddrSpace, newLock);
```

where `i` is a valid index.

However, notice that by doing so you will pay the price of default-initializing `150` `KernelLock`'s no matter what (and this might be expensive). It would be better to use the standard library:

```
std::vector<KernelLock> kernel_locks;
kernel_locks.reserve(some_size); // better to reserve if you have some sensible upper bound
kernel_locks.emplace_back(myAddrSpace, newLock);
```

Comment: You are proposing writing an array overflow.

Comment: Because `myLockArray[initializedLocksCounter]` does not exist?

Comment: As per the question, I assumed `KernelLock myLockArray[150];` to precede the assignment. If we moreover assume that `intiializedLocksCounter` is a valid index, the only problem I see is the fact that we are default-initializing 150 `KernelLock`.

Comment: I read it as `initializedLocksCounter==150`, but I don't now :)

Comment: I edited the question so as to use a generic, yet valid, `i` index :)